# How frequently is debian official docker image rebuilt and published on docker hub

Tags: docker, build, tags, debian, dockerhub

From https://hub.docker.com/r/library/debian/ I can see multiple debian official docker images are published, and for the same tagged one, e.g. debian:jessie, it is often rebuilt and re-published. I am just curious how often such tagged image is rebuilt and re-published, is it a regular scheduled rebuild and push to docker hub?